# Analytics API include subpages

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get the number of page impressions for a directory of a website using Analytics API in Google Apps Script. Here is my code:

```
function getPIs(uri, startDate, endDate) {

  var profileId = XXXXXXXX;
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;


  var optArgs = {
    'filters': 'ga:pagePath=='+uri,
  };

  var result = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    tableId,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    'ga:pageviews',
    optArgs
  );

  if (result) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

The function works perfectly but the filter doesn't include the subpages of the directory and only returns the page impressions for http://www.example.com/directory/ and not for http://www.example.com/directory/site1 etc...

Is there a way to modify the filter to include all subpages?

Comment: Use a regular expression (=~ operator and a wildcard after your url).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thank you for your help! `'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~'+uri+'*` did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment (which apparently solved the issue), you need to use  a regular expression with the `=~` operator and a wildcard after your url (although I'm not even sure Google requires the wildcard, but it easier to err on the safe side :-) ).

`==` tests for a exact match, so this returns only results for that precise url.